# Build website for receiving mail by using Asp.net core and MailKit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, mailkit

I want to build 1 website that receiving mail from gmail by using ImapClient connect to imap server of gmail.

I have one problem that when more user use my service so multi ImapClient is created, I dont know how to reuse ImapClient for per user, I dont want when page load again, asp.net create ImapClient again and connect to imap server again.

I want for per user that server create one ImapClient and use it until user disconnect

Any one have idea to resolve that problem

Comment: You can try using `Session`. See e.g. here: https://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/

Comment: Session don't keep ImapClient alive..

Comment: If you store and then later use the ImapClient within the timeout period, then Session should work fine. If an ImapClient can expire or timeout then you will just have to deal with that (detect it + create new object if needed + put that in Session). Show us what you tried.

Comment: Session does'n solve this problem. I found a solution, I save ImapClient per user to static Dictionary and it work perfectly...Now, I only find a way to dispose ImapClient from background task on asp.net core.

Comment: @HoangThanh could you please post an example?

Comment: @NIMRODMAINA I use static variable